# Converting a string to DateTime object

Tags: c#

I want to convert a string in a specific format to a `DateTime`.

My specific string format is "`dd-mm-yyyy`".

I cannot do any string manipulations.

This is the code I have right now:

```
DateTime convertedDate = DateTime.Parse(stringInput);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you want the static [`ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) method to which you can specify the actual date-time format.

```
var convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

(Depending on the context, you may also want to specify `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` instead of `null`/current culture as an argument.)

Answer (score 3):

Try [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx)

`DateTime.ParseExact("01-05-2009", "dd-MM-yyyy", null)`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a localization problem - if that is the case I recommend using one of the [overloads of DateTime.parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx) that accepts a System.IFormatProvider. From the docs:

```
Type: System.IFormatProvider
An object that supplies culture-specific format information about s.
```

This also allows your code to be flexible - if the date format ever changes in the future to support a different culture, you can just change the format provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
var convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("04-05-2010","dd-MM-yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string m = "11-02-1983";

var culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
var styles = DateTimeStyles.None;

DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(m, culture, styles, out date))
{
    //grabbed date successfully
}
else
{
    //epic fail
}
```